# Offset pagination in MySQL return inconsistent results using ORDER BY Date

Tags: mysql, datetime, pagination

I have recently found that my pagination queries in MySQL are somehow broken and, after some research, I tend to believe it comes from the fact that I paginate my rows by a DATETIME field. My issue is that some rows are shown in multiple pages and some are not shown once in my pages.

My queries typically look like that: `SELECT * FROM Table ORDER BY start ASC LIMIT 12 OFFSET 12`. The `start` column is a DATETIME and is using an index.

As far as I understand, the issue might come from the fact that multiple rows (dozens) have the exact same `start` value. I would like to ask here if some of you already faced such a situation and hopefully know what to do to correct this behavior ?

Thanks in advance for your help !

Comment: To fix this you'll need to sort by a UNIQUE criteria. For example you could add the primary key of the table to it, as in `SELECT * FROM Table ORDER BY start ASC, id ASC LIMIT 12 OFFSET 12`. This way the rows will always be sorted in the same way, and OFFSET will work correctly.

Comment: Ordering by both `start` and `id` indeed solved my issue, didn't think of that. Thank you very much for this easy solution, much appreciated !